# AngularJS creating multiple instaces of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm kinda new in Angular and I'm trying to make a simple app using the Routing module with a Parent controller and everything else being a child of that controller.The Problem is that each time the Parent Controller calls a view, a new instance of that child controller is created, wich means my functions get called multiple times, im pretty sure im doing something wrong, not sure what it is...

here's part of my app.js

```
var module = angular.module('stock', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

module.config(function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/Dashboard/', {
        templateUrl: '/Dashboard',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
    })
    .when('/Proveedores/', {
        templateUrl: '/Proveedores',
        controller: 'ProveedoresCtrl'
    })
    .when('/DatosArticulo/', {
        templateUrl: '/DatosArticulo',
        controller: 'DatosArticuloCtrl'
    })

.when('/IngresarArticulo/', {
    templateUrl: '/IngresarArticulo',
    controller: 'IngresarArticuloCtrl'
})

.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/Dashboard'
});
});
```

part of index.html

```
<body ng-app="stock" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init()" ng-cloak>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#!/IngresarArticulo">
                    <i style="font-size:22px;margin-right:8px" class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ingresar Articulo
                </a>
                <a href="#!/Proveedores">
                    <i style="font-size:22px;margin-right:8px" class="fa fa-product-hunt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Proveedores
                </a>
                <a href="#!/DatosArticulo">
                    <i style="font-size:22px;margin-right:8px" class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Datos Articulo
                </a>
            </div>

  <div style="z-index:50" id="mainContent" class="view-animate-container">
    <div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
  </div>

  <script type='text/ng-template' id='/Dashboard'>
    <!-- Magic from this view-->
  </script>
  <script type='text/ng-template' id='/Proveedores'>
     <!-- Magic from this view-->
  </script>
```

### EDIT

The Problem (to be more clear) is that I'm broadcasting an event from the Main controller to one of the childs controller, what the controller does once the event is listened is inserting data to my DB, and since there are multiple instances of that controller, the data gets inserted multiple times, how can i avoid that?

Comment: What you have described so far is actually intended behavior;  Figuring out how to make this work for you instead of against you will require seeing what the controllers are actually doing.

Comment: Don't use controllers for inserting data to DB. You should use service/factory for this actions. I think it will solve all your problems.

Comment: ok, but if the are multiple instances of a controller and i call a service, wouldn't that service be called multiple times like is happening right now?